# How to assign an "of object" procedure to a "reference to" procedure?

Tags: delphi

I have :

```
  TMyProc = reference to procedure(const adata: String);

  TMyObject = Class(Tobject)
  private
    FMyProc: TMyProc ;
  public
    Property MyProc: TMyProc read FMyProc write FMyProc;
  end;
```

and

```
  TAnObject = Class(Tobject)
  public
    procedure MyProcImpl(const adata: integer); overload;
    procedure MyProcImpl(const adata: String); overload;
  end;
```

I want to do something like

```
   MyObject.MyProc := AnObject.MyProcImpl;
```

but I get `Incompatible types: 'TMyProc' and 'Procedure of object'`. How can I do ?

Comment: Oh yeah, the edit kinda changes the question! This is why you should include an [mcve] for such questions. If you'd made one you'd have realised that your original question was incorrect. At 10k rep you should know this now. Please heed this for the future.

Comment: sorry @DavidHeffernan :( I posted the question too fastly my bad :(

Comment: You can only add event methods to an anonymous method variable (or an anonymous method, of course)

Comment: @delphi I don't really understand that statement. You don't add anything to anon method variables. You assign them. And you can assign standard procedures, i.e. not methods. And event methods aren't a thing. Events aren't part of the language. Events are just a convention for properties that are of object method types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the ambiguity introduced by the overloads. Without the overloads your code would work fine.

You can disambiguate the overloads by using a temporary variable that is typed to match the overload you want to select:

```
program SO70183946;

type
  TMyProc = reference to procedure(const adata: string);
  TMyProcOfObject = procedure(const adata: string) of object;

  TMyObject = class
  private
    FMyProc: TMyProc;
  public
    property MyProc: TMyProc read FMyProc write FMyProc;
  end;

  TAnObject = class
  public
    procedure MyProcImpl(const adata: integer); overload;
    procedure MyProcImpl(const adata: string); overload;
  end;

procedure TAnObject.MyProcImpl(const adata: integer);
begin
end;

procedure TAnObject.MyProcImpl(const adata: string);
begin
end;

var
  MyObject: TMyObject;
  AnObject: TAnObject;
  MyProcOfObject: TMyProcOfObject;

begin
  MyProcOfObject := AnObject.MyProcImpl;
  MyObject.MyProc := MyProcOfObject;
end.
```

Another way to resolve this is to write out the anonymous method explicitly instead of relying on the compiler to generate it behind the scenes:

```
MyObject.MyProc :=
  procedure(const adata: string)
  begin
    AnObject.MyProcImpl(adata);
  end;
```

Comment: thanks @davidHeffernan, another option is to declare  procedure MyProcImpl(const adata: string); overload; before procedure MyProcImpl(const adata: integer); overload;

Comment: It's interesting that one cannot define a type as "reference to procedure(const adata: string) of object;" (this is a compiler error). At first glance, such a defintion would seem to make sense. Because without the "of object" part, how does Self become captured so that it can be referenced later when the procedure is actually being called/run? Is the day saved by the fact that the closure captures the variable MyProcOfObject, and it contains the Self (data) pointer? Or does this compile due to a Delphi bug?! Combining the last two lines is an error: MyObject.MyProc := AnObject.MyProcImpl;

Comment: @MatthiasB Compiler implements `MyObject.MyProc := MyProcOfObject;` as `MyObject.MyProc := procedure(const adata: string) begin MyProcOfObject(adata); end;` and captures `MyProcOfObject` which includes the instance.

Comment: Indeed, that explains why it works - thank you! But why wouldn't this work equally well (if the syntax allowed it)? `MyObject.MyProc := AnObject.MyProcImpl;` would be implemented as `MyObject.MyProc := procedure(const adata: string) begin AnObject.MyProcImpl(adata); end;` It would capture AnObject.  EDIT: Ah, I see it myself now. Calling that wouldn't be invoking an object method. It's still invoking a regular procedure. It all makes sense, actually.

Comment: @MatthiasB Yeah, that's a good point, I've added that to the answer